# How to create dictionary inside of a list using loops?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How to turn this:

```
keys_item = ['name', 'subject', 'marks']
names = ['Rony', 'Vijay', 'Imran']
subjects = ['math', 'english', 'IT']
marks = [26, 37, 25]
```

Into this:

```
students = [{'name': Rony, 'subject': 'math', 'marks': 26}, {'name': 'Vijay', 'subject': 'english', 'marks': 37}, {'name': 'Imran', 'subject': 'IT', 'marks': 25}]
```

Using loops in Python.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a basic index iteration

```
students = []
for i in range(len(names)):
    students.append({"name": names[i], "subject": subjects[i], "marks": marks[i]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with zip function

```
students = [dict(zip(keys_item, z)) for z in zip(names, subjects, marks)]
```

With loops

```
students = []
for z in zip(names, subjects, marks):
    student.append(dict(keys_item, z))
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with list comprehension

```
print([{"name": names[i], "subject": subjects[i], "marks": marks[i]} for i in range(len(names))])
```